# get records with distinct combination of id after self join in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df.  It has columns setid, id, and label.  I would like to compare the id label values pairwise.  I've tried doing a self join as I illustrate below, but that winds up giving me extra records for each permutation of id.  I would like just one record for each distinct combination of id.  I've sketched out some examples below with data to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.  Can anyone suggest slick way to do this?

df

```
setid id label
1     1  a
1     2  b
```

if I join it to itself on setid

```
import pandas as pd

pd.merge(df,df, how='inner', on=['setid']).head()

setid id_x id_y label_x label_y
1     1    1    a       a
1     1    2    a       b
1     2    2    b       b
1     2    1    b       a
```

but I only want one version of each combination of id, for example the output below

```
setid id_x id_y label_x label_y
1     1    1    a       a
1     1    2    a       b
1     2    2    b       b
```

Comment: `pd.merge(df,df, how='inner', on=['setid']).query('id_x<=id_y')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you!  that did the trick, wishing I'd thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use np.sort

```
df1=pd.merge(df,df, how='inner', on=['setid']).head()
df1[['label_x', 'label_y']]=np.sort(df1.filter(like='label').values, axis=1)
df1=df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['label_x','label_y'])
df1
```

Comment: when I try your suggestion I get the error: "ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (808903,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,808903)"

Comment: I cant reproduce the error with the sample dataset you provided. Does your actual dataset have nans or white spaces as values?